# Why does Subversion take longer to update on one machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svn

On one of our servers (2008 R2), any SVN operations take a minimum of 30 seconds.

The repository uses HTTPS for the protocol and FSFS for the type.

If I update a specific file on my workstation, the operation takes less than two seconds. If I try it on the server, it seems to connect, wait 30 seconds, and then perform the update.

The issue occurs 100% of the times that I have observed, across all of our internal repositories I tried. I cannot test this issue with an external repository as the server does not have internet access.

It doesn't seem to be related to network issues, as I can browse the repository from the server through a web browser without any delay. The issue also manifests across both SlikSVN and TortoiseSVN.

I enabled verbose logging (using --config-option servers:global:neon-debug-mask) and the last thing that happens before the 30 second delay is the SSL identity is confirmed.

I used Wireshark to inspect the packets, and no traffic travels between the server and SVN server during the 30 second delay. After the 30 second delay, the server sends two packets that wireshark identifies as Application Data, to which the server responds promptly.

I checked the Subversion configuration in my %appdata%, and there is nothing set.

Explicitly specifying credentials on the CLI makes no difference. I also tried disabling the system's 'Detect network settings automatically' as some users reported that this impacted SVN performance, but no impact.

Other users reported that having IPv6 enabled in the network adapter can cause delays, but IPv6 is disabled.

I am unsure where to continue my investigation. Does anyone have any insight? I can provide any required information.

Comment: Note the default TCP/IP timeout waiting for a host to respond in 30 seconds. Trying to reach a server/machine with multiple IP addresses listed someplace when one no longer exists can cause this for example.

Comment: `the server sends two packets that wireshark identifies as Application Data, to which the server responds` You mean the client's sending that data, right?  And this is running `svn update` on just one particular file?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity, yes, the client is sending that data. When I did the Wireshark capture, it was for an svn update on one file, but the behavior occurs for all svn operations that communicate with the svn server.

Comment: @ShaneMadden, sorry, I forgot to notify you.

Comment: @Widdershin Can you do some digging into what the heck the SVN client is doing during that time?  Start with task manager, then if that's no good then check out [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: I did a capture using process monitor and it looks like the SVN update was timing out against some external IPs. Networking is looking into it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add more info to a possible solution.  We have had a very similar problem with subversion for a long time, our delay is about 18 secs.  All of our Dev work is disconnected from the internet.  We captured some traffic using wireshark and found that some app is requesting Windows Updates.  Since microsoft.com is not accessible the requests always need to time-out.  We believe subversion is requesting the updates but we are clueless as to why subversion would do that.